# Characteristic and minimal polynomial of A²

Tags: matrices, minimal-polynomials

Let A be a $3\times 3$ integer matrix.
If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is equal to minimal polynomial of $A,$ does it follow that 
the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$ is equal to minimal polynomial of $A^2$?

I doubt that this is true. I just don't know how and where I should start.

Please help me with this.  Thank you so much

Comment: I suggest looking for nilpotent counter-examples first.

Comment: This has more or less been answered in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120048/similarity-of-2x2-matrices), if you look again.

Comment: Im confused, is A ~ A² ??

Comment: Suppose $A^2=I$ but $A \ne \pm I$ ...

Answer (score 2):

$$
A=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
0&0&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
A^2=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1 \\
0&0&0 \\
0&0&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$